# Portable Library for Encryption AES / DES / 3DES in C++

Tags: c++, encryption, eclipse

I have a project in C++ in a specific IDE (uses some version of Eclipse as a base for the IDE) and I need to encrypt and decrypt data using AES/DES/3DES, the problem is that this IDE is something "closed" with libraries like OpenSSL , LibCurl, Boost, etc. Does anyone know any library that can be used where it is only required to link the includes ".h" and reference the library ".a" or ".so" (static/dinamic library)? Or is there some way to use OpenSSL in that same way (I think they say portable)?

I also have doubts about how to build libraries ".a" or ".so" from GitHub repositories since i am not very familiar with linux commands.

Comment: What do you mean by "closed with libraries like OpenSSL"? Do you mean that OpenSSL can not be used by code written inside this IDE?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul I mean that for example in other IDE based on Eclipse had the ability to add OpenSSL (or already came with OpenSSL) and use it as "system library" but this IDE does not allow that, instead it only gives you the ability to import libraries from a file ".so" or ".a", that's why I need a library that can be occupied only by importing it (I do not know if OpenSSL can also be used that way).

Comment: You may have more luck getting a useful answer to your question if you posted it in [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/eclipse)